# Entity Framework : When child entity is added, a duplicate parent entity is created instead of referencing existing entity?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

[image]

A product can have multiple reviews. A review is made by a single customer. 
Therefore, review has both Customer and Product as properties.

Product.cs

```
namespace DatabaseProject.Models
{
    public class Product
    {
        public Product()
        {
            Reviews = new List < Review >();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Catagory Catagory { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Specification { get; set; }
        public List<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Review.cs

```
namespace DatabaseProject.Models
{
    public class Review
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public int Stars { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Product Product { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Customer.cs

```
namespace DatabaseProject.Models
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public Customer()
        {
            Addresses = new List<Address>();
            Reviews = new List<Review>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
        public List<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Method to add new review.

I add it to the reviews list in product table.

```
public bool AddReview(int id, Review review)
{
    using (var context = new ShopDbContext())
    {
        Product oldProduct = context.Products.Find(id);
        if (oldProduct == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        oldProduct.Reviews.Add(review);


            context.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Adding a new Review

Here, since the review is added to product.Reviews I didn't have to pass the product property.

But I had to pass the customer. Somehow this creates a new customer rather than referencing the existing customer.

```
    productService.AddReview(1,
        new Review
        {
            Customer = customerService.Get(1),
            Stars = 2,
            Text = "It's a good camera",
        });
```

This causes a duplicate entry in Customers table.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a **CustomerId** propery in your Reviews table, and pass the **customerId** when adding a new review.

```
public class Review
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int Stars { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ProductId")]
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CustomerId")]
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}

productService.AddReview(1,
    new Review
    {
        CustomerId = 1,
        ProductId = XXX,
        Stars = 2,
        Text = "It's a good camera",
    })
```

Then, you would need to create a foreign key between *ProductId* and *Product* table, and *CustomerId* and *Customer* table.

In this way, you wouldn't need to load the customer/product when addign a new review. You will only need the identifiers.

Answer (score 1):

Your Review Model should have a **CustomerID** & Review Model should look like this:

```
namespace DatabaseProject.Models
{
    public class Review
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public int Stars { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ProductId")]
        public Product Product { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("CustomerId")]
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And you must add a new review like this:

```
productService.AddReview(1,
    new Review
    {
        CustomerId = 1,
        Stars = 2,
        Text = "It's a good camera",
        ProductId = 1
    })
```

In present code you are passing an object of Customer Model in `DbSet.Add method` which adds a new entity to a context